# Ubuntu eth0 not detected

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-mint, networkcard

After installing a new version of this distro, eth0 is not detected automatically.

command `inxi -SNxz` result:

```
Network:   Card-1: Broadcom NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k bus-ID: 02:00.0
```

command `ifconfig -a` result:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0                                   
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host                                        
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1                              
          RX packets:1439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                 
          TX packets:1439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0               
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                                                                                                                                             
          RX bytes:129263 (129.2 KB)  TX bytes:129263 (129.2 KB)                                                                                                                                

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:f0:2f:30:ba:59                                                                                                                                         
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0                                                                                                                        
          inet6 addr: fe80::42f0:2fff:fe30:ba59/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:502798 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:287851 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:682169370 (682.1 MB)  TX bytes:26305982 (26.3 MB)
```

System information detailes:

```
tux-world@alachiq:~ > sudo uname -a -r
Linux alachiq 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What's the output of `ifconfig -a` ?

Comment: Could you give some details about your system? Which Kernel you're running?

Answer (score 4):

Verify that you have something similar to the following in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

`eth0` could also be referred to as `p5p1` or similar according to the modern naming convention.

You can 'restart' all the network interfaces by bringing them down and up again with the following command: `ifdown --all --no-loopback && ifup --all --no-loopback` or a specific interface, eg: `ifup eth0`

If your conf seems in order, then try **`modprobe tg3`** and then bring up the network interface using `ifup`. Might be an issue regarding the drivers or lack thereof.